# Glade UI Designer with C: GtkStatusbar example?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am looking for an example of GtkStatusbar created with Glade 3 XML and C as language.
Somehow Google doesn't help. Most examples are either not with C or if they are - then GtkStatusbar is created with C functions and not with Glade.  I already have a working UI without a Statusbar.

C snippet looks like this:

```
GtkWidget *idStatusbar;   //  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusbar.html
guint  my_gtk_statusbar_context_id;

void key_Start()
{
    my_gtk_statusbar_context_id = gtk_statusbar_get_context_id( GTK_STATUSBAR(idStatusbar), "");
    gtk_statusbar_pop(GTK_STATUSBAR(idStatusbar), GPOINTER_TO_INT(my_gtk_statusbar_context_id));
    gtk_statusbar_push(GTK_STATUSBAR(idStatusbar), GPOINTER_TO_INT(my_gtk_statusbar_context_id), "Test" );
}
```

and the Glade XML snippet looks like this:

```
    <child>
      <object class="GtkStatusbar" id="idStatusbar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin-start">10</property>
        <property name="margin-end">10</property>
        <property name="margin-top">6</property>
        <property name="margin-bottom">6</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
```

I'm doing something wrong at the moment...

```
(Example_03:5638): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 02:10:24.726: gtk_statusbar_get_context_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_STATUSBAR (statusbar)' failed

(Example_03:5638): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 02:10:24.728: gtk_statusbar_pop: assertion 'GTK_IS_STATUSBAR (statusbar)' failed

(Example_03:5638): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 02:10:24.729: gtk_statusbar_push: assertion 'GTK_IS_STATUSBAR (statusbar)' failed
```

Can anyone educate me? Maybe with a clean new example? :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you initialize `idStatusbar`? I am not very familiar with Glade but last time I checked there was some function call required to retrieve the widgets that were created when loading the Glade file. Something like `gtk_builder_get_object`

Comment: Gerhardh, what does SO mean